# Scaling node on AWS

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, nginx

I currently have a small website hosted on AWS.

The server is a micro-instance. 
On this micro-instance:

- I am running nginx to serve static files and error pages
- I am running my node server
- I am storing my mongoDB

As the website is getting more traffic, I reached the time where I need to scale, and I am not sure what the best-practices are and what are the implication of each.

I would love any referrals to reading materials

I was thinking of having:

- 2 dedicated micro-instances to run the website
- 1 micro-instance running nginx
- 1 micro-instance storing the db

**questions:**

1. Would having the db stored on a separate machine make the queries 
   significantly slower?
2. Should I in fact store the db on S3 instead?
3. Is it justified to have an entire instance for nginx alone?

How would you go about scaling from 1 machine to multiple ones? I am guessing moving from one to two is harder than moving from two to 50.

Any advice will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You workload seems to be minimal. Why don't you just scale vertically and upgrade your instance from *.micro to *.small or *.medium? Balancing load between nodes is a traditional approach in the cloud, but to me it doesn't make sense just spawning multiple *.micro instances.

Comment: Well.. I mean... this is definitely the easiest way to go... but is it a long term solution?

Comment: No that's not a long-term solution and it requires down-time any time you need to scale up or down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. Would having the db stored on a separate machine make the queries significantly slower?

No, the speed impact would be very minimal, and this would be needed for scalability anyway. Just make sure you use the private IP addresses of your instances for any inter-instance communication so that the traffic stays inside your VPC (for both security and performance reasons).

> 2. Should I in fact store the db on S3 instead?

No, that wouldn't work at all. You can't store a DB on S3, only DB backups.

> 3. Is it justified to have an entire instance for nginx alone?

If you are getting enough traffic, then yes absolutely.

> How would you go about scaling from 1 machine to multiple ones?

In general you need to move your DB to a separate server, create multiple instances of your web server, and place a load balancer in front of them. If you want automatic scaling based on traffic then you would also place the web servers in an auto-scaling group. If all this sounds difficult then I would recommend looking into moving your web servers into [Elastic Beanstalk](https://aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/) which will manage much of this for you.

If your database is a bottleneck then you might also need to setup a MongoDB cluster and balance the load across the cluster. You could also move your DB to something like [mlab](https://mlab.com/) which would greatly ease the management of that as well.

Comment: Thanks Mark, The Elastic Beanstalk looks promising. I remember looking into it once, and giving that idea up for some reason. Not sure why. I sure will give it another look tonight! I would appreciate any referrals to articles discussing this migration if you know of any. As you understand, I can't risk a long down-time for the server..